# Node is not rendering the transpiled Angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, build, rendering

I have been looking for days what is the reason for not showing the transpiled Angular project correctly when I request to node and redirection occurs.
I changed default 'esnext' to 'commonjs' in order to test if it works, but it didn't work too.
Thank you in advance for the help!

[image: nodejs redirection]

[image: result obtained when ask for angular index.html]

[image: Tsconfig.json]

[image: dependencies]

Comment: Do you use Angular CLI building the Angular app?

Comment: Is that index.html screenshot made in the browser (so the index.html is downloaded to the browser, only the app is not able to start)?